# How is NB being used here - "This way there is no whole NB to getting rice from the plant"

Tags: abbreviations

I got this reply in a discussion about cooking rice and why packet rice is better.
NB is *Nota Bene* from Italian and is "Note Well" in English, but how is "Note Well" being used here.
Can someone tell me the Modern English equivalent of this?
Is it "This way there is no need to note well how to get rice from the plant", which do not seem so convincing to me!

Comment: From the context I suspect, but cannot prove, that the writer of the reply is using NB as an abbreviation for "nett benefit". If they are it's still an odd use of the term and of the abbreviation as well, but it makes more sense than Nota Bene.

Comment: @BoldBen Thanks. "Nett Benefit" makes perfect sense and the sentence is well formed with it. I had Google searched NB and found Nota Bene and so it's not something that I know from a long time, so a wrong assumption on it.

Comment: @BoldBen Yes "Nett Benefit" is a bit odd as well, but I can work with it till I get something better than it.

Comment: The title is different to the quote used in the body "no whole" vs "no need". Please fix one or the other. Thanks

Comment: @mrityunjoynath NB does not seem to be a standard abbreviation for Nett Benefit and Nett Benefit is mainly a financial industry term. It's possible that the person who posted the answer either works in or is studying finance and that NB for Nett Benefit is common in his professional and social circle. If that's the case he'll come across it meaning Nota Bene and get really confused.

Comment: Isn't 'nett' with two Ts a bit old-fashioned? It is in the UK.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey [Wikepedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(economics)) accepts it as an alternative spelling and I'm old enough go think of it as "nett".  Actually I think it's a useful difference to distinguish it from fishing nets and t'internet but I'm obviously in a minority.

Comment: I know that Wikipedia and other sources say that 'nett' is British usage, and 'net' is American, but I work in finance in the UK and very rarely see 'nett' these days. "What adjusted net income is. Adjusted net income is total taxable income before any Personal Allowances and less certain tax reliefs" - HMRC.

Comment: "Wales' net benefit from the EU equated to around £79 per head in 2014" - Wales Governance Centre at Cardiff University.